# Javascript - run a php file every X seconds

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to record the amount of seconds a person is on my site in the simplest way possible. Don't need google analytics or any other 3rd party sources.

The php script would create a connection to mysql and update the relevant values,

I found some script online, but it doesn't seem to be working:

---

```
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
       var refreshId = setInterval(function()
          $.load('timeonpage.php?wzx=<?php echo $t; ?>&ip=<?php echo $ip; ?>');
       }, 5000);
   );
</script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please define what "doesn't seem to be working" means in this context!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but using google analytics (even if it has more features than you could ever need) is far simpler than rolling your own solution

Comment: I think it will be much better to use the onbeforeunload to track the time

Comment: What is up with people still mixing JS and PHP in 2012? Then they can't figure out what is wrong with their code

Comment: Sorry Juan, not everyone is a crazy good programmer. I am trying to learn...

-----
Also, Ibu, onbeforeunload makes a person see a popup - which a lot of people hate, and some browsers don't load at all like Opera.

Comment: @JuanMendes By *mixing*, do you mean people that don't understand the rendering and execution flow or people that do not use an MVC pattern to have a better separation of the code? Nevertheless, his script, echoed inside a `php` page has odds to work - where `$t` is the initial time that the page was generated.

Comment: in your current solution, `wzx` would always have the same value, assuming `$t` is time, you wouldn't get an updated time...

Comment: So I'm trying to comprehend what is happening here, is the javascript issuing an AJAX request where some php is a part of the URL that gets executed somehow? Or the php produces literal values for `$t` and `$ip` in the javascript, which will never change, so the same values are sent up each time. So maybe OP needs to learn that PHP does not exist on the client (not without something totally nuts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error, your missing an opening to the `setInterval` function, and the closing of the `.ready` method

```
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var refreshId = setInterval(function(){ //SYNTAX ERROR HERE
        $.load('timeonpage.php?wzx=<?php echo $t; ?>&ip=<?php echo $ip; ?>');
    }, 5000);
}); // SYNTAX ERROR HERE
</script>
```

Additionally, I would recommend using the `$.get` method, as .load in JQuery is typically meant for loading HTML into a particular container:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
    $.get('timeonpage.php',{wzx:<?php echo $t?>,ip:<?php echo $ip?>});
},5000);
```

Comment: Yes, let alone [`jQuery.load`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.load/) is undocumented, while the one you mentioned ([`jQuery.fn.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) is a shorthand for `$.get` with an implicit callback to load html into the DOM as you said. As there's no html being added to the DOM, `$.get` does make more sense.

Comment: Thank you so much, that .get and error fixing did the trick. Thank you thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
 var refreshId = setInterval(function(){ //ANOTHER ERROR
    $.load('timeonpage.php?wzx=<?php echo $t; ?>&ip=<?php echo $ip; ?>');
 }, 5000);
}); //ERROR ON THIS LINE
</script>
```

Well you're missing a '}' in there on the closing of document ready. Try that, might be something so simple, report back if it's not and will have another look at it :)

Also: If you'd consider a 3rd party service, take a look at [GoSquared](https://www.gosquared.com/), seriously amazing site there :)

Edit: Another error on setInterval line :)

Answer (score 0):

With your current method, a user might be counted as online for all 86,400 seconds in a day if they just leave their browser window open.

Personally, my site is set up such that every time a user actually loads a page, their "last page loaded" time is updated. Then, a `cron` script runs every minute and checks to see which users have loaded a page in that last minute. Counting those up allows me to determine reasonably well how much time each user has spent online.

Additionally, this would cause WAY less load on your server - your solution would probably kill it if you had more than 50 or so users on your site.

Answer (score 0):

it would probably be a lot more efficient onLoad to call an Ajax script that saves the page and any other data you want to the database and then returns a unique id which you store in a variable. On the onbeforeunload event you could then make another call to the database with the unique id. Just my two cents...

Comment: That's actually exactly what I'm using now, just wanted to move away from popups.